# How can I get number of rows from passed table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function where I passed table:

```
function isEmpty(properTable){
}

var isEmpty1 = isEmpty($("#daysTable tbody"));
var isEmpty2 = isEmpty($("#daysTable2 tbody"));
```

and I don't know how I can find out whether table is empty or how many rows that table has.
I need sth like this:

```
function isEmpty(properTable){
        if((properTable tr).length > 0){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

and of course It doesn't work.

Comment: @Wendelin because that would remove nodes, not count them. "This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements. "

Comment: Use `function isEmpty(sel){ return $(sel).is(':empty'); }` and call like: `isEmpty('#daysTable tbody') // boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `.find()` with your `properTable` argument to count the rows in the table body:

Change

```
if((properTable tr).length > 0){
```

To

```
if(properTable).find('tr').length === 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant

```js
const isEmpty = (properTable) =>  $("tr", properTable).length === 0;

var isEmpty1 = isEmpty($("#daysTable1 tbody"));
var isEmpty2 = isEmpty($("#daysTable2 tbody"));

console.log(isEmpty1, isEmpty2);

// alternative

console.log(
  $("#daysTable1 tbody").is(":empty"),
  $("#daysTable2 tbody").is(":empty"),
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="daysTable1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<table id="daysTable2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can also ommit the `=== 0` and just use negation, as in `return !$("tr",properTable).length`

Comment: I could, but won't since it is harder to read.